# what is the object type of mean in R?

Tags: r, pryr

I am looking for the real object type of some functions in R, for example, I can not find out the object type of mean function.

```
> library(pryr)
> otype(mean)
[1] "base"
> ftype(mean)
[1] "s3"      "generic"
```

Sometimes the mean function is S3 and sometimes it is base!

Comment: `ftype` and `otype` are not the same. See `?ftype` and `?otype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `ftype` tell us?

> This function figures out whether the input function is a regular/primitive/internal function, a internal/S3/S4 generic, or a S3/S4/RC method. This is function is slightly simplified as it’s possible for a method from one class to be a generic for another class, but that seems like such a bad idea that hopefully no one has done it.

What does `otype` give us?

> Figure out which object system an object belongs to:
>
> • base: no class attribute
>
> • S3: class attribute, but not S4
>
> • S4: isS4, but not RC
>
> • RC: inherits from "refClass"

For reference:

1. [**`pryr`** package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pryr/pryr.pdf)
2. [R language objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Objects)